# How can I blink with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, blink

I would like to blink my menu text. I have this code, but it doesn't work with IE.

```
(function($)
{
    $.fn.blink = function(options) {
        var defaults = { delay:500 };
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        return this.each(function() {
            var obj = $(this);
            setInterval(function() {
                if($(obj).css("color") == "rgb(255, 0, 0)")
                {
                    $(obj).css('color','#000000');
                }
                else
                {
                    $(obj).css('color','rgb(255, 0, 0)');
                }
            }, options.delay);
        });
    }
}(jQuery))

$(document).ready(function(){$('.blink').blink()})
```

Can someone help me? Thank you!

Comment: you should be able to do this instinctively when your eyes get dry ..

Comment: The only way to blink is by not using blinking. Read: MY EYES ARE BURNING!

Comment: Does IE know rgb(,,)? As IE is more dumb than a stone, I'd say yes.

In this case, I would be happy when using IE :)

Comment: IE is trying to help you by not making it work. Ironically.

Comment: You could easily change the `rgb(...)` calls with `#f00` to get something you *know* is standards compliant.

Comment: @Thomas: you do know that Gecko changes everything into rgb(,,), right?

Comment: please be careful with using blink on the web, as it very easily becomes extremely distracting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Mini-Effects plug-ins](http://labs.wondergroup.com/category/frameworks/jquery/) should be simpler here--very small and clearly efficient if this is all you need from the UI Effects Library (aside from those other essentials, "throb", "shake", and "bob").

Simple to use--just load the mini-effects plugin you need, then just call blink() on the element you want to blink.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="javascripts/jquery.blink.min.js"></script>
```

Then, just call blink() on some large brightly-colored resource:

```
$(".selector").blink();
```

Comment: are you referring to the blinking rate (pretty sure it's the same as blink method in main UI Effects Library) or cross-browser fidelity or neither?

Answer (score 2):

You set obj as $(this), so you must call obj every time instead of $(obj).

Just replace

```
obj = $(this);
```

With just

```
obj = this;
```

But still think about people with epileption, bad sight, etc.

Comment: Actually, that's not relevant. Since he does `.each()` on the wrapped set, `this` in this context is just a single DOM element. By wrapping it in `$()`, he makes it a jQuery set again, but it's still just one element.

Comment: On second thought, I think you might be on to something. But it would be more effective to replace `$(obj)` with `obj` instead, and just perform the re-wrapping once.

Answer (score 1):

In explorer:

```
if($(obj).css("color") == "rgb(255, 0, 0)")
```

is not true, because IE sees this:

```
 $(obj).css("color") == "rgb(255,0,0)";
```

Without spaces between numbers.

You can fix it by changing:

```
$(obj).css('color','rgb(255, 0, 0)');

$(obj).css('color','rgb(255,0,0)');
```

and

```
if($(obj).css("color") == "rgb(255, 0, 0)")
```

to

```
if($(obj).css("color") == "rgb(255,0,0)")
```

so:

```
(function($)
{
    $.fn.blink = function(options) {
        var defaults = { delay:500 };
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        return this.each(function() {
            var obj = $(this);
            setInterval(function() {
                if($(obj).css("color") == "rgb(255,0,0)")
                {
                    $(obj).css('color','#000000');
                }
                else
                {
                    $(obj).css('color','rgb(255,0,0)');
                }
            }, options.delay);
        });
    }
}(jQuery))
$(document).ready(function(){$('.blink').blink()})
```

EDITED:

```
            (function($)
{
    $.fn.blink = function(options) {
        var defaults = { delay:500 };
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        return this.each(function() {
            var obj = $(this);
            var state = false;
            setInterval(function() {
                if(state)
                {
                    $(obj).css('color','#000000');
                    state = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    $(obj).css('color','rgb(255,0,0)');
                    state = true;
                }
            }, options.delay);
        });
    }
}(jQuery))
```

Comment: Edited. It's better to check a boolean in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the code with Firebug, or the built-in developer tools in Chrome? I would expect you need to change

```
}(jQuery))
```

into

```
})(jQuery)
```

(move the parenthesis around...)