# How to register and invoke a jquery script from code behind

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using code from [How can I blink with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361564/how-can-i-blink-with-jquery)

Code so far:

```
string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" charset=\"utf-8\" src=\"javascripts/jquery.blink.min.js\"></script>";
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "BlinkingScript", script, false);
```

Now I need to iterate through a collection and make certain items blink:

```
foreach (var notifItem in rptNotifications.Items)
{
    RepeaterItem r = (RepeaterItem)notifItem;
    HyperLink hlink = (HyperLink)r.FindControl("hlink");
    if (hlink.Text.Contains("Emerg"))
    {
        //hlink.Attributes = "$(\".selector\").blink();";
    }
}
```

Question:

How do I fix the commented out line ("//hlink.Attr...") to make the control blink?

Answer (score 0):

use `RegisterStartupScript`

this script will be registered and executed.