# Can't get JQuery plugin to work

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to follow the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361564/how-can-i-blink-with-jquery).

My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../Assets/jquery.blink.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#aaa").blink();
});
</script>
<body><a href="" id="aaa">blinking text</a></body>
```

Why doesn't this make the link blink? (the .js file is referenced correctly)

Comment: Are you including the jquery javascript file too? Does the javascript console show any errors?

Comment: see my comment for Shef's answer. no errors, just doesn't blink.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include jQuery before including:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../Assets/jquery.blink.min.js"></script>
```

???

[Blinks just fine here »](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/tLyLj/)

Comment: yes. it's used elsewhere in the project. it's included in the master page.