# <blink> in modern browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, css, blink

I'm working on a project to create a website for our CS faculty. There's one problem though. We want certain elements on the page highlighted in a meaningful manner. The solution must be cross-browser (i.e. must work in IE).

**Thus, a question:**

How to emulate `blink` (works perfectly in IE6) in modern browsers (think Chrome)?

**Update:**
I've found [this jQuery plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3361564/352796) to do the blinking, but we don't use jQuery and would prefer a CSS3 fallback for modern browsers.

Comment: [Blink](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/blink) works in Chrome 20. Why do you want to use it? It does not add any value, and it's looks very annoying.

Comment: Are you trolling, or does someone in your faculty really think that `blink` would be a meaningful way to highlight elements?

Comment: @RobW, it's in the style guide for our uni. Doesn't work in Safari (tried `[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('h1'), function (item) { item.innerHTML = item.textContent.blink(); });`).

Comment: See also [What is the replacement for a blinking text in a web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211044/what-is-the-replacement-for-a-blinking-text-in-a-web-page).

Comment: @BoltClock, not trolling. Just trying to degrade gracefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to make a class. Use the traditional tag and simply add CSS for it.

> Via Straight CSS:

```
/* Standard (Mozilla) */
@keyframes blink { from { opacity: 1; } to { opacity: 0; } }
/* Chrome & Safari */
@-webkit-keyframes blink { from { opacity: 1; } to { opacity: 0; } }
blink { -webkit-animation: blink 600ms infinite; animation: blink 600ms infinite; }
```

> Straight CSS Added Via JS

```
if ("[object HTMLUnknownElement]" === Object.prototype.toString.call(document.createElement('blink'))) {
    var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],
        style = document.createElement("style");
    /* Standard (Mozilla) */
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode("@keyframes blink { from { opacity: 1; } to { opacity: 0; } }"));
    /* Chrome & Safari */
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode("@-webkit-keyframes blink { from { opacity: 1; } to { opacity: 0; } }"));
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode("blink { -webkit-animation: blink 600ms infinite; animation: blink 600ms infinite; text-decoration: blink; }"));
    head.appendChild(style);
}
```

---

```css
/* Standard (Mozilla) */
@keyframes blink { from { opacity: 1; } to { opacity: 0; } }
/* Chrome & Safari */
@-webkit-keyframes blink { from { opacity: 1; } to { opacity: 0; } }
blink { -webkit-animation: blink 600ms infinite; animation: blink 600ms infinite; }
```

```html
<p><blink>I Blink</blink></p>
<hr />
<p><noblink>I don't</noblink></p>
```

Answer (score 10):

I wonder why no one has suggested [CSS3 Animations](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/):

```
@keyframes blink {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.blink {
  animation: blink 600ms infinite;
}
```

Demo [on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/EhUqILA/1/edit?html,css,output).

Answer (score 7):

You can just use CSS `text-decoration` property for that purpose:

For example:

```
span {
    text-decoration: blink;
}
```

Let all `span nodes` blink.. blink.. blink.. blink..

Comment: This does not work in IE/Chrome/Safari. It only works in Firefox/Opera. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-decoration#Values

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff, thank you. That's disappointing. Maybe someone should provide a universal solution.

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff: you're right. However, combining `<blink>` and a `css class` should cover some browsers. Interesting tho, that chrome and safari actually offer the option of `blink` for text-decoration, but just ignore it.

Comment: `text-decoration: blink` is part of the standard (and is not going away); browsers are simply given the permission to not actually blink the text, for obvious reasons.

Comment: This is currently disabled in every major browser: Firefox 23, Opera 15 removed it, and it's not available on Safari and Chrome according https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration.

Comment: @Dereckson No reason to downvote this answer. It is almost 3 years old, at the time this was written, it was correct and true.

Comment: The question is still available, and in 2015, this answer isn't interesting anymore, and we should instead promote another answer, like the CSS3 animations one. Maybe could you edit your answer to note the historical state of the information given?

Answer (score 4):

Here's some JavaScript to emulate `<blink>`:

```
var blink = (function () {
  var elems;

  function blink() {
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
      var visible = elems[i].style.visibility === 'visible';
      elems[i].style.visibility = visible ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
    }
  }

  this.start = function () {
    elems = document.getElementsByClassName('blink');
    setInterval(blink, 500);
  };

  return { start: start };
}());

addEventListener('load', blink.start);
```

[CodePen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJeVjW?editors=101)

Just add the class `blink` to any element.

Comment: @pbwned The website's not active any more, so Dot TK took over the domain. You can see what the link used to be in the [Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20131013082646/http://shaquin.tk/experiments/blink.html)

Answer (score 1):

just a remark : if you want to "blink" a link, it's better to change the color of the blinked text instead of hiding it because when it's hidden you can't click on it and so it's become a game to try to click on the link :-)

```
function toggleBlink() {
    for(var i = 0; i < blinkers.length; i++) {
        if(blinkers[i].style.color == 'red') {
            blinkers[i].style.color = 'white';
        } else {
            blinkers[i].style.color = 'red';
        }
    }
}
```

// "white" is the color of my background

Comment: Good catch! Invisible links can't be clicked indeed.